# How do you increase the memory limit of Vue UI

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I am working on a modestly sized vue.js project and am using the "vue ui" to compile the the app into a seperate js file for each page and it is starting to run out of memory as I add additional pages. I keep getting the following error

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Writing Node.js report to file: report.20190308.122008.16072.001.json
```

In the report it basically just points out that it is running out of memory. See snippet below.

```
"header": {
"event": "Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory",
"location": "OnFatalError",
"filename": "report.20190308.123058.23964.001.json",
"dumpEventTime": "2019-03-08T12:30:58Z",
"processId": 23964,
"commandLine": [
  "node",
  "C:\\dev\\MySite\\MySite.Admin\\MySite.Admin\\JsBuilds\\label\\node_modules\\.bin\\\\..\\@vue\\cli-service\\bin\\vue-cli-service.js",
  "build",
  "--mode",
  "development",
  "--dest",
  "../../wwwroot/vue",
  "--target",
  "app",
  "--watch",
  "--dashboard"
],
"nodejsVersion": "v11.10.1",
"wordSize": 64,
"arch": "x64",
"platform": "win32",
```

I have plenty of extra memory on my machine but don't see any way to increase the memory that vue ui uses.